# Copying parts of a powerpoint master slide without keeping the source formatting

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I have a powerpoint presentation that contains a single master slide with multiple layouts. These layouts contain a number of shapes. The collection of regular slides all have a different one of those layouts.

Now when I copy the slides to a new presentation, without keeping source formatting, for some of these slides parts of the layout are copied into a new layout under the master slide of the new presentation. However, for some this is not the case. It is very hard for me to pinpoint which setting determines whether objects from the master are copied into a new master.

I have compared XML files but both for the slide and the layout there are no differences that point me at why the layout is copied for one but not the other.

Comment: Typically this is because PowerPoint has determined that the layout of the slide you're copying is in some way different from the layout of that would ordinarily match it in the presentation you're copying it into.  For example, the layouts might have the same name but if there's a shape on one layout that's not on the other, PPT preserves both, since to do otherwise would be a data-loss situation.

Comment: That makes sense, the shapes are indeed different, but I am still looking for some form of predictability. To illustrate, my layouts can be grouped in classes of four. The variations are that one of the shapes has a different fill (picture fill). With some of the layouts, all four variations copy the background shapes (without any problem). However, with other classes one or more do not copy like this. How can I give Powerpoint the hint that the master slide shapes should be copied...

Comment: You might need to change things bit by bit and test to determine what triggers the behavior.  I've poked at it a bit but never really pinned down what causes it to assume that the master's been edited